# Query truncated at 999 character

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, truncated

I have a peculiar problem with `Postgres` and `PHP`.

I just set-up new server and although code works fine on the old server, on a new server some lengthy queries are getting truncated at 999 character.

Same page runs fine on the old one and on the new one I get an error saying

`Failed to execute query: [...], table4_name T4, table5_na`

Where it should be [...], table4_name T4, table5_name T5, [...] and so on and so on.

Basically everything after character 999 is missing.
Anyone have any idea what configuration setting may be causing that?

Comment: Could it be that the error is being cut off, and there is a different problem that actually produces an error?

Comment: Good question, let me check. Will post back in a minute.

Comment: Apparently you are right problem was elsewhere. I will see if I can fix it and if no, create another question.
If you repost your comment as an an answer I will accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My comment seems to be the answer ;)

*Could it be that the error is being cut off, and there is a different problem that actually produces an error?*